# Telegraf config to read JSON response from MQTT datalogger

Tags: mqtt, influxdb, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin

I have a MODBUS to MQTT datalooger with 2 variables configured. (it will added more variables in the future)

The payload of the MQTT message is like this:

```
{
    "date":"2023-08-25T15:59:40.0Z",
    "id":"AAAAAA020000000002301443",
    "vars":[
        {
            "name":"sonda1 > radiacion",
            "value":"0.3"
        },
        {
            "name":"sonda1 > Temperatura_celula",
            "value":"26.5"
        }
    ]
}
```

My intention is read the values in telegraf and save it in nfluxdb.
How can I parse the response to keep the name of the variable (sonda1 > radiacion and sonda1 > Temperatura_celula) and its values?

Thanks for your time and your help!

My actual config is:

```
  data_format = "json_v2"
    [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2]]      
      [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2.object]]
        path = "vars"
```